# MySQL bind-address in a Docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, remote-access, dockerfile

I would like to build a container, which enables bind to multiple IP addresses. Bind address is stored in `my.cnf`, it is okay. How to define it or maybe comment out with use of a `Dockerfile` to grant remote access?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) is usually the weapon of choice for such tasks. Taken from the official [mysql dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/ee6ac037ab647e0de9dbeb4e064610a95cb6df4a/5.7/Dockerfile#L36):

```
RUN sed -Ei 's/^(bind-address|log)/#&/' /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

The command comments out lines starting with `bind-address` or `log` in my.cnf or conf.d/*.